# Calculate value on checkbox check or uncheck

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a subtotal when a user clicks on  a checkbox.
What I'm trying to accomplish is lessen the need for static code and try to make this more generic. So if I add another row the code will just calculate the row.

Here is my table.

```
<table class="order-table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Service</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Choose</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Identification</td>
                                        <td>Identify Companies</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbHOAID" runat="server" CssClass="oClick" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>$30</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Assesment</td>
                                        <td>??</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAssesment" runat="server" CssClass="oClick" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>$25</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Payoff </td>
                                        <td>???</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbPayoff" runat="server" CssClass="oClick" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>$25</td>
                                    </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <td>Rent </td>
                                        <td>???</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRentRestrictions" runat="server" CssClass="oClick" />
                                         </td>
                                        <td>$10</td>
                                    </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <td>CC</td>
                                        <td>???</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCCR" runat="server" CssClass="oClick" />
                                         </td>
                                        <td>$75</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>Subtotal:</td>
                                        <td class="subTotal"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Here is how the table is rendered on the page.

```
<table class="order-table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Service</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Choose</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>HOA Identification</td>
                                        <td>Identify HOA and Management Companies</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="oClick"><input id="MainContent_Wizard1_cbHOAID" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Wizard1$cbHOAID" /></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>$30</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Assesment</td>
                                        <td>??</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="oClick"><input id="MainContent_Wizard1_cbAssesment" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Wizard1$cbAssesment" /></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>$25</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Payoff /Ledger</td>
                                        <td>???</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="oClick"><input id="MainContent_Wizard1_cbPayoff" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Wizard1$cbPayoff" /></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>$25</td>
                                    </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <td>Rent Restrictions</td>
                                        <td>???</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="oClick"><input id="MainContent_Wizard1_cbRentRestrictions" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Wizard1$cbRentRestrictions" /></span>
                                         </td>
                                        <td>$10</td>
                                    </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <td>CC&amp;R&#39;s</td>
                                        <td>???</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="oClick"><input id="MainContent_Wizard1_cbCCR" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Wizard1$cbCCR" /></span>
                                         </td>
                                        <td>$75</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>Subtotal:</td>
                                        <td class="subTotal"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

And here is the final Jquery.

```
    var Cart = {

$triggerBtn: $(".oClick"),
$checkBoxes: $(".oClick"),
$subTotalEl: $(".subTotal"),

calculate: function () {
    var total = 0;

    this.$triggerBtn.each(function () {
        var $field = $(this);
        var ischecked = $field.find("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked");

        if (ischecked == true) {
            var amount = $field.parent().next().text();
            var amountR = amount.replace(/\s+/g, "").replace(/\$/, "");
            var n2 = Number(amountR);
            var sum = n2;

            total += sum;
        }
    });

    total = "$" + total + " USD";

    return total;
},

trigger: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.$triggerBtn.on("click", function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var subtotal = self.calculate();            
        self.$subTotalEl.text(subtotal);
    });
},

init: function () {
    this.trigger();
    //this.$triggerBtn.trigger("click");

}
};

$(function () {
Cart.init();
});
```

**Update**

Updated javascript to show that it's now calculating properly. I still need to figure out how to get it to only calculate on click and only if the checkbox is selected.

**Update 2**
I finally figured out how to check the checkboxes and only calculate when a checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to make sure the checkbox is checked before calculating the price. Here is the final script.

If you want to see it in action see it on  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x14eLesg/1/).

```
var Cart = {

$triggerBtn: $(".oClick"),
$checkBoxes: $(".oClick"),
$subTotalEl: $(".subTotal"),

calculate: function () {
    var total = 0;

    this.$triggerBtn.each(function () {
        var $field = $(this);
        var ischecked = $field.find("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked");

        if (ischecked == true) {
            var amount = $field.parent().next().text();
            var amountR = amount.replace(/\s+/g, "").replace(/\$/, "");
            var n2 = Number(amountR);
            var sum = n2;

            total += sum;
        }
    });

    total = "$" + total + " USD";

    return total;
},

trigger: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.$triggerBtn.on("click", function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var subtotal = self.calculate();            
        self.$subTotalEl.text(subtotal);
    });
},

init: function () {
    this.trigger();
    //this.$triggerBtn.trigger("click");

}
};

$(function () {
Cart.init();
});
```